# Generating win probability from multiple different measures

Tags: probability

I am writing a program to predict the outcomes of NBA games.

I take a few things into account when determining the probability of victory for the home team but for simplicity I will just take two into account:

- The Home Team wins 58% of the time
- A Team that has played a game the previous day (Back-to-back) wins 44% of the time

Now, lets say that a want the probability of the home team winning in a back-to-back

What I have been doing is keeping a kind of score for the home and away team that is the sum of the probabilities they have to win.

In this example, the home team score would be 1.02 (.58 + .44) and the away team score would be .98 (.42 + .56)

To then calculate the probability of the home team winning I divide the home team score by the sum of the two scores.

In this example, the probability I get for the home team winning is 51% (1.02 / (1.02 + .98)).

Am I doing this correctly?  My program is accurate 60% of the time which is better than just betting on the home team but not by much. I'm worried that there are more exaggerated differences that my method is masking.

Comment: Not sure this makes a lot of sense.  What if both teams played a game the prior day?

Comment: Well then I don't take the back-to-back probability into account and I would give the home team just a 58% chance of winning.  In this particular example though, does the math check out and would it check out for any number of factors?

Comment: There are serious consistency problems.  More to the point, it's hard to imagine that "home" plus "back-to-back" are the only relevant factors.

Comment: I have more factors than just home and back-to-back I'm only using those two to keep the example simple.  What kinds of consistency problems?

Comment: Well, you can use your method to compute the probability that the home team wins.  There are four possible states according to whether or not the home and away teams played a game the prior day or not.  That computation has to yield $.58$ or else you are inconsistent with that assumption.  That sort of thing.